# HMS support for Firebase to AWS migration

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am planning to migrate their FireBase Chat to AWS Chat. The question is will AWS will support completely with our pure HMS device?

Instead of using Huawei cloud service, I am planning to use a common service to support both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If AWS relies on GMS, HMS device will not support it, otherwise it will be supported by AOSP and HMS .

Note: Huawei Cloud services are universal and do not depend on the HMS. So it is recommended to use Huawei Cloud Services, as it includes Cloud DB, Cloud Storage, Cloud Functions, and Cloud Hosting. They do not rely on HMS and  it in independent on HMS. So it ca be used as a common service for all devices.